# mysql split a string in a where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an event system and for my repeat events I am using a cron like system.

Repeat Event:

```
+----+----------+--------------+
| id | event_id | repeat_value |
+----+----------+--------------+
|  1 |       11 | *_*_*        |
|  2 |       12 | *_*_2        |
|  3 |       13 | *_*_4/2      |
|  4 |       14 | 23_*_*       |
|  5 |       15 | 30_05_*      |
+----+----------+--------------+
```

NOTE: The cron value is day_month_day of week

Event:

```
+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name                   | start_date_time     | end_date_time       |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 11 | Repeat daily           | 2014-04-30 12:00:00 | 2014-04-30 12:15:00 |
| 12 | Repeat weekly          | 2014-05-06 12:00:00 | 2014-05-06 13:00:00 |
| 13 | Repeat every two weeks | 2014-05-08 12:45:00 | 2014-05-08 13:45:00 |
| 14 | Repeat monthly         | 2014-05-23 15:15:00 | 2014-05-23 16:00:00 |
| 15 | Repeat yearly          | 2014-05-30 07:30:00 | 2014-05-30 10:15:00 |
+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Anyway I have a query to select the events:

```
SELECT *
FROM RepeatEvent
JOIN `Event` 
ON `Event`.`id` = `RepeatEvent`.`event_id`
```

That produces:

```
+----+----------+--------------+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | event_id | repeat_value | id | name                   | start_date_time     | end_date_time       |
+----+----------+--------------+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       11 | *_*_*        | 11 | Repeat daily           | 2014-04-30 12:00:00 | 2014-04-30 12:15:00 |
|  2 |       12 | *_*_2        | 12 | Repeat weekly          | 2014-05-06 12:00:00 | 2014-05-06 13:00:00 |
|  3 |       13 | *_*_4/2      | 13 | Repeat every two weeks | 2014-05-08 12:45:00 | 2014-05-08 13:45:00 |
|  4 |       14 | 23_*_*       | 14 | Repeat monthly         | 2014-05-23 15:15:00 | 2014-05-23 16:00:00 |
|  5 |       15 | 30_05_*      | 15 | Repeat yearly          | 2014-05-30 07:30:00 | 2014-05-30 10:15:00 |
+----+----------+--------------+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

However, I want to select events within a month. I will only have certain conditions: daily, weekly, every two weeks, month and yearly.
I want to put in my where clause a way to divide the string of the repeat value and if it fits any of the following conditions to show it as a result (repeatEvent is row that is being interrogated, search is the date being looked for):

```
array(3) = string_divide(repeat_value, '_')
daily = array(0)
monthy = array(1)
dayOfWeek = array(2)

if(daily == '*' && month == '*' && dayOfWeek == '*') //returns all the daily events as they will happen
    return repeatEvent

if(if(daily == '*' && month == '*' && dayOfWeek == search.dayOfWeek) //returns all the events on specific day
    return repeatEvent

if(daily == search.date && month == '*' && dayOfWeek == '*') //returns all the daily events as they will happen
    return repeatEvent

if (contains(dayOfWeek, '/'))
    array(2) = string_divide(dayOfWeek,'/')
    specificDayOfWeek = array(0);
    if(specificDayOfWeek == repeatEvent.start_date.dayNumber)
            if(timestampOf(search.timestamp)-timestampOf(repeatEvent.start_date)/604800 == (0 OR EVEN)
                return repeatEvent

if(daily == search.date && month == search.month && dayOfWeek == '*') //returns a single yearly event (shouldn't often crop up)
    return repeatEvent 

//everything else is either an unknown format of repeat_value or not an event on this day
```

To summarise I want to run a query in which the repeat value is split in the where clause and I can interrogate the split items. I have looked at cursors but the internet seems to advise against them.

I could process the results of selecting all the repeat events in PHP, however, I imagine this being very slow.

Here is what I would like to see if looking at the month of April:

```
+----------+--------------+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| event_id | repeat_value | id | name                   | start_date_time     | end_date_time       |
+----------+--------------+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|       11 | *_*_*        | 11 | Repeat daily           | 2014-04-30 12:00:00 | 2014-04-30 12:15:00 |
+----------+--------------+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Here is what I would like to see if looking at the month of May

```
+----------+--------------+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| event_id | repeat_value | id | name                   | start_date_time     | end_date_time       |
+----------+--------------+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|       11 | *_*_*        | 11 | Repeat daily           | 2014-04-30 12:00:00 | 2014-04-30 12:15:00 |
|       12 | *_*_2        | 12 | Repeat weekly          | 2014-05-06 12:00:00 | 2014-05-06 13:00:00 |
|       13 | *_*_4/2      | 13 | Repeat every two weeks | 2014-05-08 12:45:00 | 2014-05-08 13:45:00 |
|       14 | 23_*_*       | 14 | Repeat monthly         | 2014-05-23 15:15:00 | 2014-05-23 16:00:00 |
|       15 | 30_05_*      | 15 | Repeat yearly          | 2014-05-30 07:30:00 | 2014-05-30 10:15:00 |
+----------+--------------+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Here is what I would like to see if looking at the month of June

```
+----------+--------------+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| event_id | repeat_value | id | name                   | start_date_time     | end_date_time       |
+----------+--------------+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|       11 | *_*_*        | 11 | Repeat daily           | 2014-04-30 12:00:00 | 2014-04-30 12:15:00 |
|       12 | *_*_2        | 12 | Repeat weekly          | 2014-05-06 12:00:00 | 2014-05-06 13:00:00 |
|       13 | *_*_4/2      | 13 | Repeat every two weeks | 2014-05-08 12:45:00 | 2014-05-08 13:45:00 |
|       14 | 23_*_*       | 14 | Repeat monthly         | 2014-05-23 15:15:00 | 2014-05-23 16:00:00 |
+----------+--------------+----+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: can you provide a sample result you want?

Comment: Added into the question what I would like to see

Comment: @bubblebath Why would you see any output for the month of June, because the start_date_time and end_date_time interval does not include June for any of the events?

Comment: The start date and time are the start date of the origonal event and the end date time I only use the time from it for when to know how long the event time. The repeat_value effectivly overides the end date

Comment: didnt understand, can you explain it more how you want those outputs ?

Comment: Well if I look for a normal event then I will use the start and end datetime to know when the event is happening, however, I am looking for repeat events. I to look at the RepeatEvent and the associated event. I will use the event to ascertain the start date, start time and end time NOT the enddate. The enddate is now irrelevant as it is  effectivly overridden by the repeat value.

Comment: My answer below isn't good for you? :-)

Comment: Are you going to use this for a calendar? So you would like to know which event occurs on which day? Or only the actual events that happen no matter what day it is? EG a daily event: Do you get it once or 30(or 28/31) times with a date? I know your example says just once, but if it can be done in a single query with events per day, is that preferable?

Comment: How many events is in your table? I am wondering if you can't select all active rows from events and evaluate them (for example) in php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put a bandaid on this, but no one would be doing you any favors to tell you that that is the answer.

If your MySQL database can be changed I would strongly advise you to split your current column with underscores `day_month_day of year` to three separate columns, `day`, `month`, and `day_of_year`. I would also advise you to change your format to be `INT` rather than `VARCHAR`. This will make it faster and MUCH easier to search and parse, because it is designed in a way that doesn't need to be translated into computer language through complicated programs... It is most of the way there already.

Here's why:

## Reason 1: Your Table is not Optimized

Your table is not optimized and will be slowed regardless of what you choose to do at this stage. SQL is not built to have multiple values in one column. The entire point of an SQL database is to split values into different columns and rows.

The advantage to normalizing this table is that it will be far quicker to search it, and you will be able to build queries in MySQL. Take a look at [Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). It is a complicated concept, but once you get it you will avoid creating messy and complicated programs.

## Reason 2: Your Table could be tweaked slightly to harness the power of computer date/time functions.

Computers follow time based on Unix Epoch Time. It counts seconds and is always running in your computer. In fact, computers have been counting this since, as the name implies, the first Unix computer was ever switched on. Further, each computer and computer based program/system, has built in, quick date and time functions. [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) is no different.

I would also recommend also storing all of these as integers. `repeat_doy` (day of year) can easily be a `smallint` or at least a standard `int`, and instead of putting a month and day, you can put the actual 1-365 day of the year. You can use `DAY_OF_YEAR(NOW())` to input this into MySQL. To pull it back out as a date you can use `MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW),repeat_doy)`. Instead of an asterisk to signify all, you can either use 0's or NULL.

With a cron like system you probably will not need to do that sort of calculation anyway.
Instead, it will probably be easier to just measure the day of year elsewhere (every computer and language can do this. In Unix it is just `date "%j"`).

## Solution

Split your one repeat_value into three separate values and turn them all into integers based on UNIX time values. Day is 1-7 (or 0-6 for Sunday to Saturday), Month is 1-12, and day of year is 1-365 (remember, we are not including 366 because we are basing our year on an arbitrary non-leap year).

If you want to pull information in your `SELECT` query in your original format, it is much easier to use `concat` to merge the three columns than it is to try to search and split on one column. You can also easily harness built in MySQL functions to quickly turn what you pull into real, current, days, without a bunch of effort on your part.

To implement it in your SQL database:

```
+----+----------+--------------+--------------+------------+
| id | event_id | repeat_day   | repeat_month | repeat_doy |
+----+----------+--------------+--------------+------------+
|  1 |       11 |      *       |       *      |      *     | 
|  2 |       12 |      *       |       *      |      2     |
|  3 |       13 |      *       |       *      |      4/2   |
|  4 |       14 |     23       |       *      |      *     |
|  5 |       15 |     30       |       5      |      *     |
+----+----------+--------------+--------------+------------+
```

Now you should be able to build one query to get all of this data together regardless of how complicated your query. By normalizing your table, you will be able to fully harness the power of relational databases, without the headaches and hacks.

**Edit**
Hugo Delsing made a great point in the comments below. In my initial example I provided a fix to leap years for `day_of_year` in which I chose to ignore Feb 29. A much better solution removes the need for a fix. Split `day_of_year` to  `month` and  `day` with a compound index. He also has a suggestion about weeks and number of weeks, but I will just recommend you read it for more details.

Comment: I was about to give you a +1 untill you started to mess around with leap years. Just because its unlikely that somebody will schedule anything on 29 feb you just forget about leap years? And because everything after march first can be one day off, we dont use the actual year but just some year that isnt a leap year? Thats just asking for problems. Your points about splitting the value to seperate columns is however the best solution in the long run

Comment: Forgetting about leap years? If I am addressing the problem and providing a fix I am not forgetting about leap years. I will update my work to reflect an alternative to using a year that is not a leap year to base your calculations on. But it is certainly not "forgetting" if you provide a solution that makes sure leap years are not a year off. I've used too many programs where they WERE just ignored, causing problems for everyone.

Comment: Yes, you provide an alternative, but yet you still make it impossible to plan any event on the 29th of february. Call it what you want, but a calendar system that cannot be used on every day of the year is just plain wrong. No matter how unlikely and no matter how much faster queries will be.

Comment: The day of the year would not be plain wrong, because the 60th day is always March 1 except on leap years or leap centuries. We are not using this 1-365 number for anything except assigning a month and day. We can reassign the year immediately. The alternative is to assign an arbitrary number or have two separate columns, one for leap year and one for non-standard year. Which is an option because it is not actually repeating data, it just looks an awful lot like it.

Comment: I just dont see the point in storing it as a the actual day of the year. Its unclear as nobody knows from the top of their head what day EG 87 is and it can even change from year to year. Having a column month and day with a combined index is just as fast and easier to understand and less likely to cause problems. Also the DOY col isnt needed anyway. You need a DAY OF THE WEEK column and a seperate column to show if its every week, or every other week. He doesnt schedule an event to happen once every two years

Comment: You are right there. I think that gets to the crux of it and is a much better solution.

Comment: Deserved bounty for not just answering the question but providing the best solution. +1

Answer (score 2):

Try to write where condition using this:

```
substring_index(repeat_value,'_', 1)
```

instead of daily

```
substring_index(substring_index(repeat_value,'_', -2), '_', 1)
```

instead of monthly
and

```
substring_index(substring_index(repeat_value,'_', -1), '_', 1)
```

instead of dayOfWeek

Comment: While this technically works I do not advise doing this. As your system matures you will want to do more complex queries and you will find that you are using more and more - unnecessarily - complex programming to make this work. If for whatever reason you cannot go back and modify your SQL and you are looking for a bandage, though, then this works. Just don't expect it to work forever.

Comment: Sure, I agree it will be complex. But question begins with words: "I have an event system and for my repeat events I am using a cron like system." So I supposed that author doesn't want  to (or can't) change the structure of "Repeat Event" table.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overthinking the problem if you only want the events per month and not per day. Assuming that you always correctly fill the `repeat_value`, the query is very basic.

Basically all event occur every month where the `repeat_value` is either `LIKE '%_*_%'` or `LIKE '%_{month}_%'`.

Since you mentions `PHP` I'm assuming you are building the query in PHP and thus I used the same.

```
<?php
function buildQuery($searchDate) {
  //you could/should do some more checking if the date is valid if the user provides the string
  $searchDate = empty($searchDate) ? date("Y-m-d") : $searchDate;

  $splitDate = explode('-', $searchDate);
  $month = $splitDate[1];

  //Select everything that started after the searchdate
  //the \_ is because else the _ would match any char.
  $query = 'SELECT *
            FROM RepeatEvent
            JOIN `Event` 
            ON `Event`.`id` = `RepeatEvent`.`event_id`
            WHERE `Event`.`start_date_time` < \''.$searchDate.'\'
            AND
            (
              `RepeatEvent`.`repeat_value` LIKE \'%\_'.$month.'\_%\'
              OR `RepeatEvent`.`repeat_value` LIKE \'%\_*\_%\'
            )
            ';

  return $query;                
}

//show querys for all months on current day/year
for ($month = 1; $month<=12; $month++) {
  echo buildQuery(date('Y-'.$month.'-d')) . '<hr>';
}

?>
```

Now if the `repeat_value` could be wrong, you could add a simple regex check to make sure the value is always like `*_*_*` or `*_*_*/*`

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic regular expressions in MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

For a monthly event in May (first day) you can use a pattern like this (not tested):

```
[0-9\*]+\_[5\*]\_1
```

You can generate this pattern via PHP